# Inserting text from external TXT file between slides, UTF-8, macro modification

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a list of Polish words written exactly like this in the txt file: 
arbuz 
bąk
chór
cielę
ćma
dłoń
dżdżownica
dżungla
dźwig
I wish:

1. that there be a separate slide on each of these words
2. that the slides are created between already existing slides
3. that each word is in the middle of the slide
4. so that I can determine the font size.

I found this macro:

```
Sub AddSlides(text As String)
Dim Pre As Presentation
Dim Sld As Slide

Set Pre = ActivePresentation
Set Sld = Pre.Slides.Add(Index:=Pre.Slides.Count + 1, Layout:=1)
Sld.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = text
End Sub

Sub ReadFile(sFileName As String)

Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sBuf As String

' edit this:
'sFileName = "test.csv"

' does the file exist?  simpleminded test:
If Len(Dir$(sFileName)) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

iFileNum = FreeFile()
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

Do While Not EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    AddSlides (sBuf)
Loop

' close the file
Close iFileNum

End Sub

Sub SelectFile()

Dim In_file As Variant

Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(Type:=msoFileDialogOpen)

dlgOpen.AllowMultiSelect = False

If dlgOpen.Show = -1 Then
In_file = dlgOpen.SelectedItems.Item(1)
ReadFile (In_file)
End If

End Sub
```

It comes from here: [Powerpoint inserting text from external TXT file between slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062230/powerpoint-inserting-text-from-external-txt-file-between-slides)

Unfortunately, it only meets conditions 1) and 3). Moreover, it does not support Polish characters (UTF-8). How can I modify this macro?

Comment: You can use the Stream object from Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects to read your UTF-8 file.  However, where do you want the newly created slides to be positioned?  Also, what do you mean by "so that I can determine the font size"?

Comment: To make your programming simpler, create a custom layout with text centered in a text placeholder at the size you want it. Then you just have to create a new slide and insert the text.

Comment: "However, where do you want the newly created slides to be positioned?" I want like that:
1. old slide, 
new slide - "arbuz", 
2. old slide, 
new slide - "bąk", 
3. old slide, 
new slide - "chór", 
4. old slide, 
new slide - "cielę", 
etc. 
"What do you mean by <so that I can determine the font size>?" I want every new slide to have the same font I defined.

Comment: I haven't found anything like Stream Object, but there is a TextStream object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/textstream-object). Is that it? If so, how to use it? @JohnKorchok this macro already creates separate slides and pastes text in the middle. I need to specify the size and font name for this. I'd like to do it in a macro.

Comment: I gave up the idea of doing this project at PP. It is much easier for me in JS with swiper.js library. Anyway, thanks for your help and regards.